# CodeDomProvider Code Generation Fails in Web Project but not Console App

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using the CodeDomProvider to compile some C# code in-memory and then execute the code. Everything works fine when I run the code in a Console application. It compiles and I can execute it and get a result.

However, this same exact code fails when I try to run it inside a web application. I get a BadImageFormatException and the inner exception is Bad IL Format.

Is there some restriction with web applications vs. console application that I'm unaware of?

Thanks for any suggestions.

I'm running .NET 4.0.

**Edit:** I've noticed that everything works until I add a reference to another assembly from the project. So I have a class library with a project reference that contains my entity model. I'm adding it as a reference like:

```
CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Linq.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Entity.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("MyApp.Data.dll");

var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, source);
var assm = results.CompiledAssembly;
```

If I just make my class have a single method that returns a string and remove the add reference to the MyApp.Data.dll then everything works. As soon as I add that reference back in it fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it failed on adding the referenced assembly I did some Binging and came across [this discussion](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-scripting/805/Dynamic-Code-Referenced-Assemblies-from-ASP-NET). Basically it was an issue with need to use Server.MapPath so that the code could find the dll.

```
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("bin\\MyApp.Data.dll"));
```

Now it works! So it was a simple mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

I create code on the fly from web apps in nearly every project I have done in the last year, so it is definitely possible/practical.

Security would be a possible difference but you would receive a permission exception, probably not `BadImageFormatException`.

Another difference is that the default build profile for a console app is `x86 4.0 Client Profile`, whereas the default for a web app is `Any CPU, 4.0.`

You may want to post your actual code; someone may spot a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it was something simple. :) I'll post some code shortly.