# CodeDomProvider Code Generation Fails With Certain Linq Syntax

Tags: c#, compilation

I'm using the [CodeDomProvider to compile some Linq code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9577139/10893) and execute queries dynamically. However, I'm hitting a very strange issue.

If my Linq query in the generated code looks like this everything works:

```
namespace Dynamic
{
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public static class Query
    {
        public static int GetRecords()
        {
            MyData.Data.DataMart container = new MyData.Data.DataMart();
            return (container.EventDetails).Count();
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs just fine. However, if I change the linq query to the following then it fails to compile:

```
return (from e in container.EventDetails select e).Count();
```

It works fine if I put this as static code, but if I try to compile it with the CodeDomProvider it fails (and I haven't found any good method to get error messages on why it fails). I would like to use the from-in-select style of syntax since this will make it easier for me to generate the linq queries but I can't figure out why they are not compiling.

You can see some of the code I use to compile this snippet at the link on the top of this post.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Copying the code from the post I linked to:

```
CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Linq.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Entity.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("MyApp.Data.dll");

var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, source);
var assm = results.CompiledAssembly;
```

**Edit2:** As far as the exception goes, I get an exception on the second to last line of code (var results = ...). The exception is a BadImageFormatException:

> Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format

Comment: Which problem should we solve here? The fact that you cannot get good error information from the attempt to compile it is surely more important (since any future efforts may have similar issues). Can you include your compilation code?

Comment: I would assume if you could get me the error information that would solve both issues at the same time. :) The MyApp.Data.dll is contains my Entity Framework entities.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeDomProvider Code Generation Fails in Web Project but not Console App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577139/codedomprovider-code-generation-fails-in-web-project-but-not-console-app)

Comment: I don't know your exact problem, but why you try to use your dynamic linq provider? you can't use [Dynamic linq library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)?

Comment: Saeed, it is not a duplicate (I wrote both questions). I don't want to use the Dynamic Linq Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an answer of how to get good exception information, however, I did solve this problem. The class library that contained the compiler code above was set to AnyCpu but the context it was running in under ASP.Net was x86. So this was causing it to fail when it tried to load System.dll since it was loading the wrong version (or something silly like that).

I'll be happy to give someone else the answer checkmark if you can (a) figure out how to get a real error message from this or (b) load the right reference type.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceCode = @"namespace Dynamic {
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Query
{
    public static int GetRecords()
    {
        MyApp.Data.DataMart container = new MyApp.Data.DataMart();
        //return (container.EventDetails).Count();
        return (from e in container.EventDetails select e).Count();
    }
} }";

        string sDynamDll = "Dynamic.dll";
        string sDynamClass = "Query";
        string sDynamMethod = "GetRecords";

        System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
        cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
        cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
        cp.OutputAssembly = sDynamDll;
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Linq.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.Entity.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("MyApp.Data.dll");

        var providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0");
        CodeDomProvider compiler = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#", providerOptions);
        CompilerResults cr = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sourceCode);
        if (cr.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
            foreach (CompilerError error in cr.Errors)
            {
                errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n", error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
            }
        }

        // verify assembly
        Assembly theDllAssembly = null;
        if (cp.GenerateInMemory)
            theDllAssembly = cr.CompiledAssembly;
        else
            theDllAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(sDynamDll);

        Type theClassType = theDllAssembly.GetType(sDynamClass);

        foreach (Type type in theDllAssembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsClass == true)
            {
                if (type.FullName.EndsWith("." + sDynamClass))
                {
                    theClassType = type;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // invoke the method
        if (theClassType != null)
        {
            object[] method_args = new object[] { };

            Object rslt = theClassType.InvokeMember(
                sDynamMethod,
              BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                   null,
                   null, // for static class
                   method_args);

            Console.WriteLine("Results are: " + rslt.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting `BadImageFormatException` because your code isn't actually compiling to a valid assembly. This might be  because the old 2.0 compiler is used by default. Check the link below for enabling the C# the 3.5 version (I don't know if 4.0 is supported, but you don't need it):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/07/11/c-3-0-and-codedom.aspx

Also check the `Errors` collection on the `CompilerResult` that is returned from the `CompileAssemblyFromSource()` method. Failure to compile does not throw an exception, you must manually check for compile errors.

Comment: I tried using the CompilerVersion setting and got the same results. It does throw an exception on the compile unless I set GenerateInMemory to false. But even if I set that to false I get zero errors in the Errors collection.